# Why am I getting the error react-resizable module not found?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have this resizable box component using the react-resizable library. I have downloaded the library and also the type declarations. But for some reason I am getting this error

Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-resizable' in '/Users/ChristopherDobbs/public-ui/src/user/pages/Payments/PaymentHeaders/PaymentsCharts/PaymentsChartComponents'

My code is as follows

```
import React, {ReactNode} from 'react';
import {ResizableBox as ReactResizableBox} from 'react-resizable';

import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';

interface IResizableBoxProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    resizable: boolean;
    style: {};
    className?: string;
}

export default function ResizableBox({
    children,
    width = 600,
    height = 300,
    resizable = true,
    style = {},
    className = '',
}: IResizableBoxProps): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div style={{marginLeft: 20}}>
            <div
                style={{
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    width: 'auto',
                    background: 'white',
                    padding: '.5rem',
                    borderRadius: '0.5rem',
                    boxShadow: '0 30px 40px rgba(0,0,0,.1)',
                    ...style,
                }}
            >
                {resizable ? (
                    <ReactResizableBox width={width} height={height}>
                        <div
                            style={{
                                width: '100%',
                                height: '100%',
                            }}
                            className={className}
                        >
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    </ReactResizableBox>
                ) : (
                    <div
                        style={{
                            width: `${width}px`,
                            height: `${height}px`,
                        }}
                        className={className}
                    >
                        {children}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried messing around with the imports but it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: in your pakage.json, do u have 'react-resizable' yet?

Comment: Yes I do. But maybe its not right. I ran the installation script and it said 'resizable' instead of react-resizable

Comment: Actually I just tried reinstalling it again and it worked but now there is a different error

Comment: It doesn't like my style: {} declaration now.

Comment: I think it had installed resizable instead of react resizable. It works now.